# Trying to parse a vector of structures, compiler error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile the following code.

```
/* 5 structures of type 'kv'  will be created and stored
 in a vector named 'listing'
'kv' will have just 2 member variables of type int: key , val
Then the 'listing' will be filled with 4-digit random numbers.
Then the elements of the 'listing' will be parsed, converted into
string, will be divided in 2 substrings of equal lengths, and
consecutively increasing numbers from 0 to 4 will be added between
those substring and the newly formed 5-digit string  will be printed.   
*/

/* EXPECTED SAMPLE OUTPUT
93017
72192
92286
89317 
73455
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct kv {  
  int key;
  int val; };

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int i;
  int num = 10;
  string s;
  int rnd;

  vector<kv> listing;
  srand (time(NULL));

  for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
    rnd = 1000 + rand() % 8999;
    kv tmp{.key=i, .val=rnd};
    listing.push_back(tmp);
  }
  vector<kv>::iterator p = listing.begin();    
  while (p !=listing.end()) {
    s = to_string(p.val);
    cout << s.substr(0,2) << *p.key << s.substr(2,2) << endl;
  }
}
```

Compilation gives this error:

```
'std::vector<kv>::iterator' has no member named 'key'
   50 |     cout << s.substr(0,2) << *p.key << s.substr(2,2) << endl;
      |                                 ^~~
```

How to correct this error?

Comment: (*p).key or p->key ...

Comment: `p` is an iterator. It must be dereferenced first. `p->key` for example. `(*p).key` is also legal. You *almost* do it correctly once in the code. Consistency is always key. You could avoid all of that with a range-based for loop, though.

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with operator precedence. `*p.key` parses as `*(p.key)` rather than `(*p).key`. You can either do the latter manually, or use the `->` operator: `p->key`.

Comment: There's also one instance where they attempt the dot operator directly.

Answer (score 0):

You run into trouble with [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). What you wrote:`*p.key`
is evaluated as `*(p.key)`. To get the wanted order, use brackets `(*p).key`. I prefer the pointer to member syntax like `p->key`.